# Twig - interpolating variables

Tags: php, symfony, twig, templating

I have the following:

```
{% if promo.monday_unavailable == 1 %} 
    not available mondays 
{% elseif promo.monday_available == 1%}
    available mondays 
{% else %}
    available mondays from {{promo.monday_start}} until {{promo.monday_end}}
{% endif %}
<br />
{% if promo.tuesday_unavailable == 1 %} 
    not available tuesdays 
{% elseif promo.tuesday_available == 1%}
    available tuesdays 
{% else %}
    available tuesdays from {{promo.tuesday_start}} until {{promo.tuesday_end}}
{% endif %}
<br />
```

...

That I would like to do for each day of the week.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can simplify the code to read

```
{% for i in ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'] %}

{% if promo.~i~"_unavailable" == 1 %} 
    not available mondays 
{% elseif promo.~i~"_available" == 1%}
    available mondays 
{% else %}
    available mondays from {{promo.~i~"_start"}} until {{promo.~i~"_end"}}
{% endif %}
<br />

{% endfor %}
```

With Twig.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm at a loss for what keywords to search for anymore.

Answer (score 14):

I know this is an old thread but twig has support for inline interpolation like:

```
{{i18n("language_#{langId}")}}
```

Important that the string to interpolated is with double-quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Found answer by mashing my forehead on the keyboard.

rather than

```
{% if promo.~i~"_unavailable" == 1 %}
```

use

```
{% promo[i~"_unavailable"] == 1 %)
```

Comment: I would add that in case `promo` is an object is has to implement `ArrayAccess` interface (at least for Twig version 1.16). And it seems then, Twig will access the object properties using the interface implementation before using getters as explained in Twig documentation [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables)

Comment: You can also use the string interpolation feature `promo["#{i}_unavailable"]`, like explained in [Twig documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#string-interpolation) (version 1.16)

Answer (score -1):

You can try using my code

```
{% for i in ['monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'] %}
    {% set key = i ~ '__unavailable' %}

    {% if (promo[key]) eq something %}
        //
    {% endif %}
{% endfor}
```

Comment: Please never, ever post code-only answers on Stack Overflow.  **Every** answer should include an educational explanation with the intent of helping the OP and thousands of future researchers.

Comment: @mickmackusa "never ever" is wildly too strong. Many answers are fine with code only.

Comment: Code with explanatory comments is fine